# Meta Refresh page, load content but wait until called to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to use MetaRefresh in my HTML/CSS/Javascript website where as the refresh is called at say 20s but will load and wait until 25s before switching to the new content. Effectively allowing the server 5 seconds to respond and get ready while the user is still shown the existing page.

It's important the timing is right because the content on the page is rotating every 5 seconds, and needs to refresh back to the beginning as soon as the last "frame" has made it to the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: show a load screen `meta-refreshing` is not recommended

Comment: Why not? In this context the user won't be actually browsing the webpage but will only be looking at the content. Couldn't care less about the "back button" not working or users becoming frustrated the control of the page is being taken away from them... because that's what they expect.

Comment: There is no particular reason `meta-refreshing` is generally avoided, instead use `$.ajax{}`. ajax will allow your page to wait for data from the server